# Lookup a specific instance of a value in a column based on other columns?

Tags: excel

I have an event time and employee number and need to match this to corresponding shift start and end times as shown in yellow. Sounds simple manually but there are 690000 events and employees undertake many shifts in this time (some crossing midnight).

main table(left), reference table(right)

[image]

Comment: VLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH, and XLOOKUP will all do this.

Comment: Do you know how I’d do it @ScottCraner? I know how to use vlookup and index/match to find first instance of an employee but can’t figure out how to get the correct shift times from each event.

Comment: I came up with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72329358/how-can-i-make-this-run-more-efficiently